# What do I need to use to be able to store a string from an HTML form to a database?

Tags: html, sql-server, database, jsp

I'm trying to develop a simple web app and I'm wondering how I would go about storing a string value from an HTML form to a database. Do I need to use PHP? I tried googling for an answer and everything points me towards PHP. Is it harder to use JSP?  Where do I learn how to incorporate a server side language with my front-end javascript/html?

Answer (score 0):

You can choose any programming language to fulfill your requirement. But yes it is a fact that most of the reference you will get in php. I guess due the large number of developers are using php. I am also a php developer and i also think that you can get into php more quickly than other languages but that is my personal opinion.

But you are free to choose any one. The thing you are trying is a basic task and can be easily achievable from any. So do some research on any programming language you like and you will do great.

Hope this will help.Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need PHP or another server-side programming language to store a string in your database. When a form is submitted, the server-side language can read it and store it.

PHP is easy to start with, you can set up a running 'server' on you own computer, for development. Just download:

- Xammp
- MySQL workbench (to control your MySQL-databases)

Note: you can use other databases like sql server if you like. PHP has functions to connect with those. Just look them up.

When you have a form, you can give it the attributes method and action. Action is the script you want to run, like: `process.php`

If you use `method="get"` in your form you can read out the value in PHP by using `$_GET['nameofthevaluehere'];` If you use `method="post"`, then you can read out the value in PHP using `$_POST['nameofthevaluehere'];`

So make 2 files:
1. index.html
2. process.php

The first file should contain the form:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The second the script:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
//make a connection and stuff and write the SQL query
$query = "INSERT INTO table VALUES ('$name')";

?>
```